# Logstash HTTP input with SSL keystore

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, ssl-certificate, logstash

**What I want:**

I want to send logs using "Postman" to http logstash input with SSL.

**What I already done:**

1. I added SSL configuration in my **logstash.conf** file using http plugin: https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-logstash-input-http-plugin

> ```
> input {
>   http {
>         port => "5000"
>         ssl => on
>         keystore => "keystore.jks"
>         keystore_password => "1qaz@WSX"
>   }
> }
> ```

Then I needed keystore.jks. Next steps are taken from: https://blogs.oracle.com/blogbypuneeth/steps-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-openssl

2. I created private key **cakey.pem** and public certyficate **cacert.pem**

> ```
> openssl req 
>  -newkey rsa:2048 
>  -x509
>  -keyout cakey.pem 
>  -out cacert.pem 
>  -days 3650
> ```

3. I created **keystore.p12** using **cakey.pem** and **cacert.pem**

> ```
> openssl pkcs12 
>  -export 
>  -in cacert.pem 
>  -inkey cakey.pem
>  -certfile cacert.pem 
>  -out keystore.p12
> ```

4. I convert **keystore.p12** to **keystore.jks**

> ```
> keytool
>  -importkeystore 
>  -srckeystore keystore.p12 
>  -srcstoretype pkcs12 
>  -destkeystore keystore.jks 
>  -deststoretype JKS
> ```

5. When I try send logs using "Postman" nothing happen - "Postman" show "Could not get any response" - It should be "ok". Curl respons:

> ```
>  curl: (52) Empty reply from server
> ```

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your http input, change

```
ssl => on
```

to

```
ssl => true
```